# Compare two dates when subtract a days from one of them

Tags: php

I'm trying for some time to compare two dates and return the result.
And echo if the file is older than 2 days from now.
Here is mine code:

```
$filename = './Sample.htm';
$filedate = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', filemtime($filename));
$date = new DateTime('-2 days');
$noData = '';
if ($filedate > $date->format('d/m/Y H:i:s')) {
$Data = "<p>The file is created in the last 2 days!</p>";
} else {
$Data = "<p>The file is older than 2 days</p>";
}
echo $Data;
```

The code works only if i compare in same month range. If the file is in another month it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do it the other way around, you want to compare DateTime objects, not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filemtime` [returns “a Unix timestamp”](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) without modification. If you compare with `$date->format('U')` instead, you’ll have a much easier time.

```
$filename = './Sample.htm';
$fileAge = filemtime($filename);
$twoDaysAgo = new DateTime('-2 days');
$noData = '';
if ($fileAge > $twoDaysAgo->format('U')) {
    $Data = "<p>The file is created in the last 2 days!</p>";
} else {
    $Data = "<p>The file is older than 2 days</p>";
}
echo $Data;
```

*Or*, convert both to `DateTime` objects and then compare.